# Extra slash comes in json array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I works on nestable drag and drop. When I drag and drop tiles It generate an array in textarea which is `[{},{"id":267},{"id":266}]`. Now When I post this array in action page then It posted `[{},{\"id\":267},{\"id\":266}]`. Why this extra slash comes in array. In action page I convert this array using json_decode. Now How I remove this slash from array or how I ignore this array that I successfully decode this array through jsondecode.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var updateOutput = function(e)
    {
        var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
            output = list.data('output');
        if (window.JSON) {
            output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));//, null, 2));
        } else {
            output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
        }
    };

    // activate Nestable for list 1
    $('#rightservices').nestable({
        group: 1
    })
    .on('change', updateOutput);

    // output initial serialised data
    updateOutput($('#rightservices').data('output', $('#siteservices')));


    //$('#nestable3').nestable();

});
```

Comment: Can you post your code please :)

Comment: Somewhere in your code it is being escaped , which is not unusual. Post the relevant code

Comment: Are the extra slashes appearing on the browser side, or are they only appearing in the $_POST variables in PHP? Which version of PHP?

Comment: It comes in $_POST variables in action page

Comment: Yes but how? Can you provide the code........

Comment: Where is the problem? JSON.parse() removes escaping

Comment: I write a code with question

Comment: Still haven't identified where there is any problem. The json parsers will manage the escaping

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I solve this extra slash issue using stripslashes function. As stripslashes removes slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Magic Quotes is set on the server. This is an old, deprecated, feature of PHP where any request data would be automatically escaped with slashes regardless of what is was. You can follow the instructions [listed here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) to disable them. From that page, any of these should work, depending on what you have access to:

#### In php.ini

This is the most efficient option, if you have access to php.ini.

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

#### In .htaccess

If you don't have access to php.ini:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

#### At runtime

This is inefficient, only use if you can't use the above settings.

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will remove the first object in the array but doesn't really solve the real issue of why it is being added in the first place?

```
var arr = [{},{\"id\":267},{\"id\":266}];
arr.splice(0,1);
```